# Android Game online, how to communicate with remote database

Tags: java, android, networking, network-programming

As it happens in online games, the data should be constantly updated. I currently do this with a retrofit  and handler.postDelayed() that sends requests every second or half. However, it is probably not a very effective way because after a few seconds my internet chokes and starts to lag I guess those requests are the reason.

So the question is, how to send queries to the database from Android so as not to overload the Internet so much and how to do this effectively.

Comment: Unclear how you have architected your game app/backend. If you are communicating with your server that frequently, see: [How to write a network game?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/249/6883)

Comment: What would you like to know? Backend was written in Spring Boot.

Comment: Question as written is too broad. StackOverflow is for specific programming questions. Frequent communication with server has its own issues (including server side architecture, i.e who is slow - server, network, client) which if you read my link has a number of resources and possible solutions and I'm using that link as a starting point for your research.